# What is the "moddable version" of Serious Sam 3?

Tags: serious-sam-3-bfe

On the very first launch of SS3, I am met with this dilemma:

[image]

What's the difference between "Serious Sam 3: BFE" and its "moddable version"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "moddable version" loads user mods, while picking the first option loads the vanilla game.  If you've got no mods installed (as this is your first time loading it & the game is so new there aren't any), they both essentially do the same thing.

The same option was available in the second Serious Sam game, although it [had its issues](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1526241) at launch.

Comment: Is the point that the game won't count achievements or records made in the 'moddable version'?

Comment: I haven't played this version to confirm, but I assume it's either achievements disabled or multiplayer disabled.

Comment: Achievements and leaderboards are disabled. Not sure about multiplayer.